# Programmatically get current CPU frequency

Tags: android, linux

I am trying to fetch **current cpu frequency** and update it to the UI periodically.

As below screenshot shows, I was able to get min/max cpu frequency by reading **cpuinfo_min_freq** and **cpuinfo_max_freq** files.
What I am stuck is I don't know how to get current cpu frequency as cpuinfo_cur_freq requires root access.

I know this can be done because I've downloaded many apps (including CPU Stats) that is able to show current cpu frequency.

[image: Screen from CPU Stats app]

Appreciate your help.

thanks!